# How to prevent IIS Express from running when I press stop in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I'm debugging an email batch procedure and I'm checking if the email is well formatted through the [Papercut SMTP server](http://papercut.codeplex.com/).

The batch is executed from a command on our intranet which was created in ASP.NET MVC 2. Recently we've made the switch to IIS Express because of its improved performance. One thing is bugging me though: if I put a *breakpoint in a loop* in order to evaluate some variables, once I press STOP in visual studio, IIS Express just execute the rest of the loop.

How can I make Visual Studio stop the application completely in IIS Express?